# Google Extension CSP inline javascript error when creating buttons (one for each website which is added)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension which downloads files from specified websites by the user. What I am doing now is making the list of websites and a button next to each website to download the files from that website. I guess the problem is I don't understand the inline policy for extensions by chrome, but everytime i hit click i get the:

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   chrome-extension-resource:".

I have looked around this mistake and tried different solutions but non worked. Any help? thank you!

This is the code:

```
    //printURLs receives an array of TrackedWebsites and print the urls on the main popup
    //It prints also the button to download the files from that website

function printURLs(websites){
  var i;
  var elem = document.getElementById("websitesList");
  console.log(websites);
  for (i = 0; i<websites.length; i++){          
        var node = document.createElement("li");
        var url = document.createTextNode(websites[i].get_URL);
        var downloadButton = document.createElement('input');
        downloadButton.setAttribute('type','button');
        downloadButton.setAttribute('name','down'+i);
        downloadButton.setAttribute('value','DL');                               
        downloadButton.setAttribute("onclick","clickDownloadFiles(websites[i])");
        console.log(websites[i].get_URL);               
        node.appendChild(url);
        node.appendChild(downloadButton);
        elem.appendChild(node);
   }
 }



 function clickDownloadFiles(website){

        var filesURLs = retrieveFilesURLs(website);
        downloadFiles(filesURLs);
    }
```

Comment: Read about closures in loops and the article about the [csp](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

Comment: I did before posting this and i can't understand what I have done wrong, as everything is in an external javascript file. Thank you anyway ;)

Comment: You've already solved the problem, but just to be crystal-clear: "everything is in an external javascript file" is not true. You were trying to inject inline script back into the page again with the setAttribute(onclick) line. See how the value you're injecting (clickDownloadFiles(...)) is JavaScript? That's the problem.

Comment: Ok, I understand it now. By setting that attribute, the function is like if its defined in thr html. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a string to the `onclick` attribute is implicit eval, hence it violates the [Content security policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

The proper way to get rid of this error is to use a function instead.

```
downloadButton.setAttribute("onclick", "clickDownloadFiles(websites[i])");
// should be
downloadButton.onclick = function(e) { clickDownloadFiles(websites[i]); };
```

Another problem with current method is that all `onclick` handlers share the same `i` variable. If your `websites` object is a true array, just use the [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method. Otherwise, you have to [add a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) or store the `i` variable as an element attribute.

```
websites.forEach(function(website, i) {
    ...
    downloadButton.onclick = function(e) {
        clickDownloadFiles(website);
    };
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly with the forEach as it was a  true array. Can you explain me why the (e) in function(e) if it is not used?

Comment: You can leave out the `e` if you wish. I often declare "e", "ev" or "event" in event listeners out of habit.